# loop can't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

may i know how come when i duplicate more for the div.box with different data-type, which is data-type="c1" and data-type="c2",the all div will run the same content for data=type="c1"?

```
html :
// Should be 
<div class="box" data-type="c1" id="cp_1">
    <div class="cp-title">c1 title</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-type="c2" id="cp_2">
    <div class="cp-title">c2 title</div>
</div>
```

i want make output like above sample,which is when data-type=c2,the content should is c2-title. but currently it run same content with data-type=c1 which like sample below.

```
// currently
<div class="box" data-type="c1" id="cp_1">
    <div class="cp-title">c1 title</div>
</div>
<div class="box" data-type="c2" id="cp_2">
    <div class="cp-title">c1 title</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(function() {
// document
    'use strict';

    var cp = $('div.box');
    // unique id
    var idCp = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cp.length; i++) {
      idCp++;
      cp[i].id = "cp_" + idCp;
    }

    // diffrent type
    if (cp.data('type') == "c1") 
    {
        cp.addClass('red').css(
            {
                "background: 'red',
                "padding": "20px", 
                "display": "table"}
            );
        $('.box').append('<div class="cp-title">'+ 'c1-title' + '</div>');
    } 

    else if (cp.data('type') == "c2") 
    {
        cp.addClass('green').css(
            {
                "background" : 'green',
                "padding": "20px", 
                "display": "table"}
            );
        $('.box').append('<div class="cp-title">'+ 'c2-title' + '</div>');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});//end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `$(xx).each` for iterating your elements collection `var cp = $('div.box')` .

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Please notice the second argument is DOM element, you need to make it jquery element by wrapper `$(this)`